# Assign user a custom password CakePHP AuthComponent and Blowfish hash

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am using Blowfish to hash a password before save in my model like so:

```
...

$passHash = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passHash->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);

...
```

I am using a MySQL backend and obviously I can't just assign a password in the password field for that user because it will never authenticate with the Auth Components authentication because it is using the Blowfish hasher.

So, how could I assign a user a custom password for them to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With advice from a co-worker, I ended up creating a shell script to manage users.

In Console/Command I created *UserShell.php* which has an updatePassword function which takes a username and a password as arguments. In the function I set the user using the username, and then use the following to save a custom password that is hashed by the models beforeFilter

set the user...

```
$this->User->saveField('password', $password);
```

This was a quick solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have an edit method in the users model with a corresponding view baked up? You can edit the users password there and It'll take care of password hashing if you send a password to the database that way.

Comment: Problem with this is it takes a lot of overhead.. I would need Admin authentication, the view, controller, model, etc...